# How to combine GreenSock's (GSAP) ScrollTrigger and TextPlugin

Tags: gsap, scrolltrigger

How can I combine ScrollTrigger with their different plugins, e.g. TextPlugin?
Like tweening

```
<h2 id="tweenthat">That</h2>
```

to

```
<h2 id="tweenthat">This</h2>
```

when `#tweenthat` comes into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ScrollTrigger can be added to any tween or timeline (in addition to being created in a standalone way). So just create the animation that you want then attach it to a ScrollTrigger. For example: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/LYZrjqJ

```
gsap.to("#myText", {
  duration: 2, 
  text: "thank you for waiting", 
  delay: 1,
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#myText"
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI you're more likely to get an ever faster reply over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).